# How to remove an attribute from an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <ol>
        <li id="ItsMyKitchen">It's My Kitchen</li>

         <div id="mykitchen" hidden>
             <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="200px" width="200px"/>
             <ul>
                 <li>Pizza</li>
                 <li>Camorised Oinon rice</li>
                 <li>Jollof</li>
                 <li>Banku with Okor</li>
                 <li>Fufu</li>
                 <li>Spanish Omellet</li>
                 <li>Fried Rice with Beef</li>
                 <li>Steamed Rice with Curry Chicken</li>
                 <li>Yong Chow Fried Rice </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

i want to remove the "hidden" attribute from the div element that has "mykitchen" as the id. Am using this javascript code

```
var ItsMyKitchen1 = document.getElementById("ItsMyKitchen");

ItsMyKitchen1.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("myKitchen").removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```

but it seems not to be working. any help

Comment: It works. Why you say it doesnt?

Comment: Your ID don't match? `mykitchen` vs `ItsMyKitchen`.

Comment: Where are you click? This element id is "ItsMyKitchen"?

Comment: IDs are case sensitive. Your JavaScript has `getElementById("myKitchen")` your html has `id="mykitchen`

Answer (score 2):

You've created your div with id `mykitchen`, but when you try to get the element by id, you're trying to select a div with id `myKitchen`.  Try making those two match, and then your code should work as expected. 
 Your use of [element.removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) is correct, but capitalization matters for element ids!

Comment: ok i have matched the id's but still not working, when i click on element it doesn't remove the hidden attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way.

```
document.getElementById("mykitchen").addEventListener("load", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mykitchen").removeAttribute("hidden"); 
}
```